# Which will be Best Level for Setting Obfuscating Mobile jar

Tags: java-me

In J2ME, Which Obfuscation level will be efficient for running Application in Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifically talking about the obfuscation level available in NetBeans? Proguard, the obfuscator used doesn't have anything called a level, You could see the various parameters that each level passes to the underlying proguard while you move the slider.

You could learn more about proguard here
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html